# Qt Quick 1.1 visual lags on x property change

Tags: qt

I try test Qt Quick 1.1 on linux (Ubuntu and Embedded), need marquee text from right to left.
The code demonstrate these:

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 480
    height: 200

    MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        Qt.quit();
    }
    }

    Text {
    smooth: true
    style: Text.Raised
    styleColor: "transparent"
    font: font.pixelSize = 100
    text: "Hello World 1 Hello World 2 Hello World 3"
    NumberAnimation on x {loops: Animation.Infinite; from:360; to:-1500; duration: 9000}
    }
}
```

Possible show text more smoothly?

Comment: Describe in more detail what you’re seeing. Is the scrolling laggy? On which hardware? Check your OpenGL setup and consider using Qt 5/QtQuick 2 if that’s an option, for much improved performance.

Comment: Can't use Qt 5/QtQuick 2, due no support it my embedded device. How to check OpenGL?

Comment: For example video on Core i5 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdvbFF-KADs